DOCTYPE is disallowed for gradle build
Trying to build Spring framework. Ran into the following with Gradle 7.5.1
./gradlew build

> Task :buildSrc:compileJava FAILED
[Fatal Error] japicmp-gradle-plugin-0.3.0.pom:2:10: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':buildSrc:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve me.champeau.gradle:japicmp-gradle-plugin:0.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :buildSrc
      > Could not resolve me.champeau.gradle:japicmp-gradle-plugin:0.3.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/me/champeau/gradle/japicmp-gradle-plugin/0.3.0/japicmp-gradle-plugin-0.3.0.pom
            > DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.


How do I get gradle to ignore this? Is this an issue with the specific plugin?

Similar question and question. Try to update the japicmp-gradle-plugin version to the latest one (at the moment of writing is 0.4.1)

@Raptor thanks for the links. I looked at both earlier but did not offer any clues. I upgraded to 0.4.1 after I posted this and it continues to fail with that version too. [Fatal Error] japicmp-gradle-plugin-0.4.1.pom:2:10: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.

If the problem still persists after clean and rebuild, perhaps you can ask in their GitHub issues: https://github.com/melix/japicmp-gradle-plugin/issues. By the way, your Gradle can be upgraded to version 8.x as well.
